# Let me know before I spend an hour writing that you won't accept answers from my account

Tags: feature-request

When I start answering a question, your software seems to know what I'm doing, or should.  How come you wait until I spend 20 minutes to an hour trying to answer a question, then go to post it and your system says something like "We're not accepting answers to this account at this time...".  Can't save it, a total waste of time.  I've had a couple of these, and they are very frustrating.  I don't attempt to answer many questions anymore, because of this. Please NOT let us enter information YOU KNOW you won't take...

Comment: I agree that should be pointed out before attempting to answer, but you really should rephrase this so that it doesn't look like a rant. That won't help your feature-request to go through.

Comment: @kos If someone is upset because of something, that should be more reason for the site's management to pay *more* attention to the issue, not less.  Don't treat your users like you treat your children.

Comment: @kos That's fair, and I agree that it's not worded in a way that is ideal.  However, it's a new user and they can't be expected to know best practices for asking questions.  The point I make is that concerns they have should be taken seriously even if they are a new user and even if they do not word them tactfully.